# HTML5 tags vs <div> just for the sanity?

Tags: html

Other than having a structure that makes more sense (i.e wrapping a footer with a `<footer>` tag) why should i be using html5 tags over div tags?

If i use `<div>` i will still be able to use some of the sweet html5 features, so why should i worry about learning all this new tags?

> P.S: I am aware of video and audio tags that make it easier to embed media

Comment: +1 I'd like to know too. Incompatibility with older browsers is obviously a factor... isn't it?

Comment: when it comes to tags, i think is not that complicated to take care of browser compatibility although you do have to rely on javascript (i have used http://remysharp.com/2009/01/07/html5-enabling-script/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using those tags will help search engine index your site, and for screen reader, etc.  This is known as "semantic correctness".

Comment: Search engines have been dealing with tabled based sites for years, do you think html5 will make any difference in the way my site is index right now? (real question)

Comment: any help can be nice, I think, if you have a `nav`, then search engine can have higher certainty that it is the navigation panel, and then some search engines may put you in higher ranking if your page is more certain than those that are not as clear what the page structure is... and there are Yahoo, Bing besides Google too

Answer (score 6):

```
<div>This is an advertisement about big rubber flashlights</div>
<div>This is the actual content of the current page, an important article about the state of the world we live in</div>
<div>Here a user posts that he hates everything about this place</div>
```

The second div i guess would benefit a lot by being replaced with the `<article>` tag, as a web bot, gadget or browser can see that this is probably the main topic of the page.

Answer (score 6):

Tags like `footer`, `section` etc are all included in HTML5 as a move towards the semantic web. You can learn more about the [semantic web on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web). In a nutshell the semantic web helps search engines understand the content on your site better which would (hopefully) result in more accurate search rankings. It also means programmers can write code that parses your site more accurately, for example browser makers can incorporate features in their browsers that react to the semantics of a web page.